# GKE master is not responding

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google, google-kubernetes-engine

The control panel says there is a problem with my cluster. No buttons available. I can't do anything. It started more than 16 hours ago, and now whole cluster went down. (500/502 on most of the services). I wish I could create new cluster and migrate, but some persistent data stored within cluster. 
I've tried to find something related to my case, but seems google doesn't detect any problem in their cloud. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38100621/how-to-restart-unresponsive-kubernetes-master-in-gke

I won't use managed GKE anymore, just help me get it back online so I can move everything to bare metal kube.

[Control panel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9IGX.jpg)
[No nodes detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7TT1.jpg)

Comment: Can you confirm your billing is ok? How did you create those PV, its google standard? Did you make any changes in last 24 hours? Did you have any HPA/CA? Did you have configured logging?

Comment: Also can you run cloud shell and execute any `kubectl` command (ex. `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`)